# `minipage` of a specific aspect ratio

Tags: minipage

Consider this MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
\fbox{%
  \begin{minipage}[c][7in][t]{3in}
    \lipsum[3-4]
  \end{minipage}%
}
\end{document}
```

I want to be able to produce a `minipage` of a specific aspect ratio that fits perfectly around the included text.

So, if the total text area flown naturally is 8sq cm and we are aiming for a aspect ratio of 2, then it should be a minipage of width of about 4cm and height of half of that, etc.

How do I do that?

Comment: Unrelated: remember a `%` after `\end{minipage}` or there will be an extra space

Comment: @daleif Thanks. Added.

Comment: Typset the content in a box (with a fixed `\linewidth`). Measure the height of this box. From these determine the appropriate `width` and `height` and then re-typeset the material into a minipage of the computed `width`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure to completely understand the question, but I guess that you want to set the width (fourth argument) as a multiple of the height (second argument).

If the height is hard-coded or defined by a LaTeX length, you can use :

```
\begin{minipage}[c][<myheight>][t]{\dimexpr 2<myheight>\relax}
```

where `<myheight>` can be any LaTeX length like `\linewidth` , and 2 can be replaced by any literal floating number.

**Edit:**
If the whole thing must be dynamic (i.e. you don't know in advance what would be neither the height nor the width, you can use a `\savebox` to measure the "area", and then compute the new dimensions to fit the prescribed aspect-ratio. The whole procedure is wrapped in the `\miniaspect` macro in the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage[margin=2cm,landscape]{geometry}
\usepackage{xfp}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\miniaspect[2]{
   \ifdefined\tmpbox\else\newsavebox\tmpbox\fi
   \ifdefined\newheight\else\newlength\newheight\fi
   \savebox{\tmpbox}{\parbox{0.5\linewidth}{#2}}
   \def\tt{\fpeval{sqrt({\strip@pt\wd\tmpbox}*({\strip@pt \ht\tmpbox}%
    +{\strip@pt\dp\tmpbox})/#1)}}%
    \setlength{\newheight}{\dimexpr\tt pt\relax}%
    \fbox{%
    \begin{minipage}[c][\newheight][t]{\dimexpr #1\newheight\relax}%
    #2
    \end{minipage}%
}}
\makeatother    
\begin{document}
\noindent\miniaspect{2}{\lipsum[3-4]}   %width=2*height
\noindent\miniaspect{0.8}{\lipsum[3-4]} %width=0.8*height
\end{document}
```

Here i used the `xfp` package to make the calculation as we need to get a square root, and defined a wide page (using `geometry`), as even for a medium-sized text like `\lipsum[3-4]`, the resulting box with aspect-ratio 2 becomes very wide.

Comment: Thanks. I needed it to be dynamic. So the box would perfectly fit the content and have a desired aspect ratio. The version you have posted produces boxes of correct aspect ratio but the contents do not fit perfectly in the box. There is either some space at the bottom or the text overflows the box. What could it be?

Comment: Actually i made a small copy-paste error the width was used instead of the height in
`{\strip@pt\wd\tmpbox}*({\strip@pt\ht\tmpbox}+{\strip@pt\dp\tmpbox})`. I have edited the MWE in mt ansver, For better behavior, I also inculded the initial declaratio in the macro.

Comment: In some circumstances, the new height can be one line two small or too large by one `\baselineskip` because the reformatting induces new line-breaks, thus not preserving the final area. This can not be obvious with `\lipsum` as it produces full paragraphs.  If the constraint on the aspectratio is not too strong, this can be overcome by simply omitiong the new height of the final minipage, with:
`\begin{minipage}[c][][t]{\dimexpr #1\newheight\relax}`

Comment: Thanks. This works splendidly.